# Is there a better way to create index for headings and sub-headings of a document in python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of headings and subheadings of a document.

```
test_list = ['heading', 'heading','sub-heading', 'sub-heading', 'heading', 'sub-heading', 'sub-sub-heading', 'sub-sub-heading', 'sub-heading', 'sub-heading', 'sub-sub-heading', 'sub-sub-heading','sub-sub-heading', 'heading']
```

I want to assign unique index to each of the heading and the subheading like follows:

```
seg_ids = ['1', '2', '2_1', '2_2', '3', '3_1', '3_1_1', '3_1_2', '3_2', '3_3', '3_3_1', '3_3_2', '3_3_3', '4']
```

This is my code to create this result but it is messy and it is restricted to depth 3. If there is any document with a sub-sub-sub heading the code would become more complicated. Is there any pythonic way to do this?

```
seg_ids = []
for idx, an_ele in enumerate(test_list):
    
    head_id = 0
    subh_id = 0
    subsubh_id = 0
    if an_ele == 'heading' and idx == 0:  # if it is the first element 
        head_id = '1'
        seg_ids.append(head_id)
        
        
    else:
        last_seg_ids = seg_ids[idx-1].split('_')  # find the depth of the last element
        head_id = last_seg_ids[0]
        
        if len(last_seg_ids) == 2:  
            subh_id = last_seg_ids[1]
        elif len(last_seg_ids) == 3:
            subh_id = last_seg_ids[1]
            subsubh_id = last_seg_ids[2]
            
           
        if an_ele == 'heading':
            head_id= str(int(head_id)+1) 
            subh_id = 0  # reset sub_heading index 
            subsubh_id = 0 # reset sub_sub_heading index 

        elif an_ele == 'sub-heading':
            subh_id= str(int(subh_id)+1)
            subsubh_id = 0  # reset sub_sub_heading index 
        elif an_ele == 'sub-sub-heading':
            subsubh_id= str(int(subsubh_id)+1)
        else:
            print('ERROR')
            
        
        if subsubh_id==0:
            if subh_id !=0:
                seg_ids.append(head_id+'_'+subh_id)
                
            else:
                seg_ids.append(head_id)
                
        if subsubh_id !=0:
            seg_ids.append(str(head_id)+'_'+str(subh_id)+'_'+str(subsubh_id))
            
          
            
print(seg_ids)
```

Comment: You have to generalize this.  Don't store the level IDs in variables.  Use a list.  Then, have  function that translates your header strings to a level number.  If the new level is indented from the last, you start it from 1.  Otherwise, you bump whatever the last index for the new level was.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to store level IDs in list?

Comment: What I said was "DON'T store the level IDs in variables.  Use a list."  See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_level(s):
    return s.count('-')

def translate(test_list):
    seg_ids = []
    levels = [0]*9
    last_level = 99
    for an_ele in test_list:
        level = get_level(an_ele)
        if level <= last_level:
            levels[level] += 1
        else:
            levels[level] = 1
        seg_ids.append( '_'.join(str(k) for k in levels[:level+1]))
        last_level = level
    return seg_ids

print(translate(['heading', 'heading','sub-heading', 'sub-heading', 'heading', 'sub-heading', 'sub-sub-heading', 'sub-sub-heading', 'sub-heading', 'sub-heading', 'sub-sub-heading', 'sub-sub-heading','sub-sub-heading', 'heading']))
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '2_1', '2_2', '3', '3_1', '3_1_1', '3_1_2', '3_2', '3_3', '3_3_1', '3_3_2', '3_3_3', '4']
```

This fixes the maximum number of levels at 9.  You could extend that by setting `levels=[0]` and then extending it if the new level was beyond the end, but this gets the point across.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `split('-')` method to find the level of the heading:

```
subs_amount = an_ele.split('-')
```

You can deduce the level of the heading from the length of the `subs_amount` list. If the length is 1, then it is a `"heading"`. If it's 3, it is a `"sub-sub-heading"`. Etc.
Then, have a list `store_levels` to store the indexes of the previous headings of greater level, like Tim Roberts says in their comment:

```
if len(subs_amount) > len(store_levels):
    store_levels.append(1) #add a sub-level
elif len(subs_amount) == len(store_levels):
    store_levels[-1] += 1 #add a heading of the same level
else:
    del store_levels[-1] #go back to the level above
```

Now, to build your output, you just have to `"_".join(store_levels)` and append it to the output.

---

Sorry for not using the same variable names as you. I did so not to confuse or change their use. I hope my code is clear enough so you can implement it to yours.